# datetime.strptime does not supports reentrant locking

Tags: python-3.x, signals, python-datetime

I have a process which needs to send an update to a database every 10 mins irrespective of what it is doing currently. In order to achieve that, I am using SIGALRM signal which gets invoked every 10mins.

I have written custom manager which takes care of setting up Alarm handlers one after the other. I have also written a wrapper **'parse'** which internally calls datetime.strptime

**Problem:**
My process kept on getting stuck transiently. Upon debugging, I found that this happens whenever my main code flow is inside datetime.strptime and SIGALRM gets triggered which internally also calls the same parse method.

I have written a small reproducer to reproduce this problem

```
from foo.abc import AlarmManager, Alarm
from foo.xyz import parse
from  os import getpid

pid = getpid()

def alarm_handler():
    print("Alarm triggered " + str(pid))
    parse('08/25/2020 20:22:30 IST', "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
    alarm = Alarm(0.1, alarm_handler)
    AlarmManager.add(alarm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alarm = Alarm(0.1, alarm_handler)
    AlarmManager.add(alarm)
    while True:
        parse('08/25/2020 20:22:30 IST', "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

This code kept on getting stuck after executing for a couple of minutes. Upon attaching gdb, I got the below stack trace

```
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
  <built-in method __enter__ of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7fee7849b450>
  File "/opt/python/python-3.7/lib64/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 329, in _strptime
    with _cache_lock:
  File "/opt/python/python-3.7/lib64/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  <built-in method strptime of type object at remote 0x7fee8ad10be0>
  File
```

**Question:**
Is there any alternative to datetime.strptime which supports reentrant locking? Or Is there a better way, I can handle the above use case?

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with reentrant locking - did you make sure `datetime.strptime('08/25/2020 20:22:30 IST', "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z")` actually works on your system? `IST` is not guaranteed to be parsed by `%Z`.

Comment: I checked and the above datetime.strptime works with IST on my system